# Pass variables into AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am connecting to an API through a script (init.js) when starting my angular app. I then receive som information such as a username and a user ID that I want to define as global values to use in the AngularJS App.

How do I pass the variables on to use in the AngularJS app?

My thought now is to define the variables in the MainController to be able to use them anywhere.

**init.js**

```
(function () {
function appStart() {
    //Get variables
    var userId = 123;
    var username = 'This is my name';

    //Init Angular App
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); //How do I use the variables in the angular app?
}

function genericError() {
    console.error('Something went wrong');
}

TT.native.init()
.done(appStart)
.fail(genericError);
})();
```

**app.js**

```
(function () { //Start
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
'myControllers',
'myDirectives',
'myFilters',
'myServices',

'ui.router'
]);
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myControllers', []);

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.userName = ""; //I want to use the variable from INIT.JS here
    $scope.userId = 0; //I want to use the variable from INIT.JS here
});
```

Comment: Why don't you connect the api within angular app?

Comment: How would I do that? I don't know how to. I am using this system based on jQuery that needs to have the init code look like that.

Comment: You can build a service for your first code block (to get the user data). Then you can call it in a run block within angularjs (app.run(...)). After that point whenever you need these variables, you can call them from that service. I know it might be too much for a beginner in angular, but that's a consistent and "angular" way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be:

```
var userId = -1;
var username = '';
(function () {
function appStart() {
    //Get variables
    userId = 123;
    username = 'This is my name';

    //Init Angular App
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); //How do I use the variables in the angular app?
}

function genericError() {
    console.error('Something went wrong');
}

TT.native.init()
.done(appStart)
.fail(genericError);
})();
```

Then in the controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.userName = userId;
    $scope.userId = username;
});
```

But just know that this is not a good approach. You should connect to your api within the angular app. Maybe you should watch and read some tutorials before beginning to code...

Comment: Thank you! In what way is it not a good approach? I would very much like to see how I could do it within the Angular app. before the first state is loaded. If I could perform the same thing there as right now in init.js, that would of course be great!

Comment: Start digging services (factory method) and run method of angularjs. And accept this as correct answer if it's a solution for the moment...

Comment: okay, would be helpful though to know in what way it is a bad approach so I can analyze if it will be a lasting solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.module('myApp').value` or `angular.module('myApp').constant` before bootstrapping angular. In your controller you should add variables into dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a good approach. Could you please provide an example? I am not an experienced coder.

Comment: Okay, so I can add the values. But how do I set the variables to the .value when I bootstrap angular?

Comment: angular.module('myApp').value('userName', userName)

Comment: I've figured out that part, but not how to get the userName value there from the init.js when I run: `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);`

Comment: app.controller('MainController',['$scope', '$state', 'userName', function ($scope, $state, userName) {
    $scope.userName = userId;
    $scope.userId = username;
}]);

Answer (score 0):

You probably using ngRouter or uiRouter so you could `resolve` the `TT.native.init` before entering the first route/state.

Comment: Yes, using Ui router. How would I do that? Could you put it into code?